# How to add multiple form fields based on user inputting initials to select the field using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an Adobe form that will allow my customers to select services by inputting their initials. How do I get the "total" field to show the total price for the services selected based on the user's selection using JavaScript?

I.E.: I have 3 optional services that a customer can select (one has to be selected, the other to are optional add-ons).

Comment: Do you mind please posting more details ? snippets of your code ?

Comment: Below is what I have so far. So the user customer will be presented with a .pdf form where they would have to initial 1 of 3 fields. After initialing the desired fields, then the total field will automatically add up the desired services.

function myFunction () {
var initial1 = opt1;
var initial2 = opt2;
var initial3 = opt3;
var x = 100;
var y = 75;
var z = 25;

 if (!initial1) {
  opt1 = x;
 } else {
  opt1 = 0;
 }
 
 if (!initial2) {
  opt2 = y;
 } else {
  opt2 = 0;
 }
 
 if (!initial3) {
  opt3 = z;
 } else {
  opt3 = 0;
 }
 
 return opt1 + opt2 + opt3;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to have an input that store the total price of selected services. So try something like this:

```js
var service1 = document.querySelector('#service1');
var service2 = document.querySelector('#service2');
var total = document.querySelector('#total');

service1.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  var currentPrice = service1.options[service1.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-price');
  var service2Price = service2.options[service2.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-price');
  total.value = parseInt(currentPrice) + parseInt(service2Price);
});

service2.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  var currentPrice = service2.options[service2.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-price');
  var service1Price = service1.options[service1.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-price');
  total.value = parseInt(currentPrice) + parseInt(service1Price);
});
```

```html
<select id="service1">
  <option value="1" data-price="50">Service 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="100">Service 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-price="150">Service 3</option>
</select>

<select id="service2">
  <option value="1" data-price="25">Service 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="75">Service 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-price="125">Service 3</option>
</select>

<input type="number" placeholder="Total" id="total" />
```

Comment: This is close but looking to have the customer input their initials to make the selection.

Comment: Even though this did not work for the original purposes, this works for another application that I am working on. Thanks.